# Create a plugin from within Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

Is it possible to create a plugin directly from the admin panel?

I cannot find any such plugin to create plugins with when searching, and that really makes me curious. Are there security risks with this that simply prevent people from developing such a thing? Or is the file system inaccessible for creating files?

As far as I can see, a rather simple plugin could create the fundamental php-files in the right wp directory. And from there on it just must allow you to create more files within this directory. The built-in plugin editor in Wordpress can take it from there.

Does such a tool exist? And if not, why?

Answer (score 3):

Why would anybody create such a tool? Creating a plugin [is really easy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/):

> At its simplest, a WordPress plugin is a PHP file with a WordPress plugin header comment.

Here is the plugin header:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
*/
```

Just save the above text to a new PHP file, upload it to the **plugins** folder in WP and you're done.

Of course, you only succeeded in creating the basic plugin, now you need to put the code that actually does something.

Answer (score 1):

What will happen if a website is hacked ?

If anyone can create file it will be a very high security hole.

Some Host simple disabled theme and plugin editor for various reason but the first is security.

As Mihai said, it is very simple to create a plugin file and you can find a lot of plugin to inject PHP code related to theme.